# Sublime Text 2 save_settings to file

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

Hi I'm working on a Sublime Text 2 plugin and I need to read and write settings to a `.sublime-settings` file

```
settings = sublime.load_settings('OracleExplorer.sublime-settings')
settings.set('defaultConnection', 1)
sublime.save_settings('OracleExplorer.sublime-settings')
sublime.message_dialog(str(idCon))
```

Sublime reads the settings file, but doesn't write changes to file when I fire `sublime.save_settings()`

PS. I use Windows 7 OS.

Edit: I've found out that Sublime saves settings to another file in `Packages/User/`. Can I teach him to save it in plugin folder?

Comment: It works at my side. Any error message? Where is the file `OracleExplorer.sublime-settings`? Is it in the same directory as plugin?

Comment: No, there are no errors, `OracleExplorer.sublime-settings` is in plugin folder (`Packages/OracleExplorer`). But Sublime saves settings in `Packages/User/OracleExplorer.sublime-settings`. Is there a proper way to work with settings files? Because I need to have one file to keep connection settings and etc.